# Modifying a CSS file to fit my asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, tabs

I found a CSS file while I was searching for how to create tabs without using images.  I came across [CSS Tabs 2.0](http://unraveled.com/publications/assets/css_tabs/)

which serves my purpose.
However, now I need to customize it to fit my asp.net page, and I can't seem to be able to get anywhere.
The CSS file uses a `<ul` and an `<li`
I am using a Table with `<tr>` and `<td>`

**This is the sample code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>CSS Tabs | unraveled</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<!-- CSS Tabs is licensed under Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/ -->

<style type="text/css">

/* begin css tabs */

ul#tabnav { /* general settings */
text-align: left; /* set to left, right or center */
margin: 1em 0 1em 0; /* set margins as desired */
font: bold 11px verdana, arial, sans-serif; /* set font as desired */
border-bottom: 1px solid #6c6; /* set border COLOR as desired */
list-style-type: none;
padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; /* THIRD number must change with respect to padding-top (X) below */
}

ul#tabnav li { /* do not change */
display: inline;
}

body#tab1 li.tab1, body#tab2 li.tab2, body#tab3 li.tab3, body#tab4 li.tab4 { /* settings for selected tab */
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; /* set border color to page background color */
background-color: #fff; /* set background color to match above border color */
}

body#tab1 li.tab1 a, body#tab2 li.tab2 a, body#tab3 li.tab3 a, body#tab4 li.tab4 a { /* settings for selected tab link */
background-color: #fff; /* set selected tab background color as desired */
color: #000; /* set selected tab link color as desired */
position: relative;
top: 1px;
padding-top: 4px; /* must change with respect to padding (X) above and below */
}

ul#tabnav li a { /* settings for all tab links */
padding: 3px 4px; /* set padding (tab size) as desired; FIRST number must change with respect to padding-top (X) above */
border: 1px solid #6c6; /* set border COLOR as desired; usually matches border color specified in #tabnav */
background-color: #cfc; /* set unselected tab background color as desired */
color: #666; /* set unselected tab link color as desired */
margin-right: 0px; /* set additional spacing between tabs as desired */
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: none;
}

ul#tabnav a:hover { /* settings for hover effect */
background: #fff; /* set desired hover color */
}

/* end css tabs */

</style>
</head>

<body id="tab1">

<p><a href="/publications/css_tabs/">&#8592; Introduction</a></p>

<h1>CSS Tabs 2.0</h1>

<ul id="tabnav">
    <li class="tab1"><a href="index.html">Tab One</a></li>
    <li class="tab2"><a href="index2.html">Tab Two</a></li>
    <li class="tab3"><a href="index3.html">Tab Three</a></li>
    <li class="tab4"><a href="index4.html">Tab Four</a></li>

</ul>

<p>CSS Tabs is licensed under <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/">Creative Commons Attribution 3.0</a>.</p>

<p>Joshua Kaufman, <a href="/">unraveled</a><br />
28 January, 2007</p>

<a href="css_tabs_v1.html">Looking for CSS Tabs 1.0?</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<style type="text/css">

/* begin css tabs */

ul#tabnav { /* general settings */
text-align: left; /* set to left, right or center */
margin: 1em 0 1em 0; /* set margins as desired */
font: bold 11px verdana, arial, sans-serif; /* set font as desired */
border-bottom: 1px solid #6c6; /* set border COLOR as desired */
list-style-type: none;
padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; /* THIRD number must change with respect to padding-top (X) below */
}

ul#tabnav li { /* do not change */
display: inline;
}

body#tab1 li.tab1, body#tab2 li.tab2, body#tab3 li.tab3, body#tab4 li.tab4 { /* settings for selected tab */
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; /* set border color to page background color */
background-color: #cc6666; /* set background color to match above border color */
}

body#tab1 li.tab1 a, body#tab2 li.tab2 a, body#tab3 li.tab3 a, body#tab4 li.tab4 a { /* settings for selected tab link */
background-color: #fff; /* set selected tab background color as desired */
color: #000; /* set selected tab link color as desired */
position: relative;
top: 1px;
padding-top: 4px; /* must change with respect to padding (X) above and below */
}

ul#tabnav li a { /* settings for all tab links */
padding: 3px 4px; /* set padding (tab size) as desired; FIRST number must change with respect to padding-top (X) above */
border: 1px solid #6c6; /* set border COLOR as desired; usually matches border color specified in #tabnav */
background-color: #ffffff; /* set unselected tab background color as desired */
color: #666; /* set unselected tab link color as desired */
margin-right: 0px; /* set additional spacing between tabs as desired */
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: none;
}

ul#tabnav a:hover { /* settings for hover effect */
background: #cc6600; /* set desired hover color */
}

/* end css tabs */

</style>
</head>


            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" ID="Table1">
                <tr>
                    <td width="15"></td>
                    <td valign="bottom">
                        <%--Generate Home Tab--%>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" ID="Table0">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><div align="center" class="tab1"><a href="index.aspx">Home</a></div></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td width="3"></td>
                    <td>
                        <%--Generate CRM Tab--%>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" ID="Table1">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><div align="center" id="Contact"><a href="Contact.aspx" class="Tab2" id="tabnav" title="Contact">Contact</a></div></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I would appreciate anyones help to make the tabs work in my code.

Comment: So you want someone to take your current website, and modify it for you to use Tabs 2.0? It might be nice if you at least tried it yourself first and then asked for assistance.

Comment: table's tr and td are exactly for building table. I am not sure if you can easily make them to tabs. Why don't you just change it to ul/li or something like that?

Comment: @Sheen, the current code has tables, tr and td, which in turn have the runat=server tag, and are being manipulated in the code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the jQuery UI Tabs, the work is already done for you:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: yea, but using jQuery would make my life easy... unfortunately I am not allowed to use jquery because of security reasons (end client is not allowed to is a huge security sensitive shop)

Comment: You can still use the online sample to fashion good semantic HTML and CSS :)

Comment: The jQuery sample also uses ui & li... which is the same issue I am having in my o/p

Comment: Presuming that applying the CSS to the bullet list was your problem, this shows you how to apply it. Tables are for tabular data and shouldn't really be used in this scenario.